# Remote debugging : Do I need source code on target machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

Our application runs perfectly fine on our machine, but it fails and crashes miserably on our client's machine. I am sure this is due to some memory leak problem.

Since I do not want to share my code with client, I am not asking them to install Visual Studio for debugging. They have given me access to their PC using Team Viewer

I have never used remote debugging and have no idea, how it works. So the basic question is :

Can I debug my application (Windows form application C++, developed using MS VS 2010 on windows 7) on clients's PC (Windows 7 ), remotely from my PC , without actually compiling the  code on the client's machine?
I will just give them the exe (and a software for debugging if required).

If the answer is yes, kindly provide me a tutorial link to understand the complete procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can install the remote debugging tools on the PC and then connect to that PC after opening the relevant ports. Heres a video showing most of the steps but very similar to VS 2010 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEp6VqUg2WE

Ideally you would want to trap all errors and write to the log. I would suggest to look at the event viewer to see if that gives any help.

You dont need to provide the source code but if you use the pdb files that would help to debug.

Finally add try catch blocks so that all errors are caught or even display errors during development and then chose how you wish to tackle them.